# Why does std::span lack cbegin and cend methods?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, std-span

Why does `std::span` only have `begin` and `end` methods and not their constant iterator counterparts `cbegin` and `cend`? ([standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/span.iterators))

What I noticed too is that the proposals for span that I could find do have a definition for `cbegin` and `cend`: [P0122R7](https://wg21.link/p0122r7). Why was it removed?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As an update, these are added back by [P2278R4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2278r4.html). The LWG issue pointed out below is still a problem, `x.cbegin()` and `std::cbegin(x)` would do different things, but now `x.cbegin()` and `std::ranges::cbegin(x)` do the same thing.

---

This was removed as a result of [LWG3320](https://wg21.link/lwg3320).

The issue is that `x.cbegin()` should really do the same thing as `std::begin(std::as_const(x))`, which is what `std::cbegin(x)` is defined as.

But that's not the case for `std::span`, because it doesn't actually own its elements and, as a result, only has shallow const. Given `span<int> s;`, `s.cbegin()` would've given you an `int const*`<sup>†</sup> while `std::cbegin(s)` gives you an `int*`. That's very inconsistent. Could've kept `s.cbegin()` while having it just return `begin()` (as proposed by [PL 247](https://github.com/cplusplus/nbballot/issues/243)), but that's arguably confusing, so the resolution decision was to simply remove all the const members and aliases.

In any case, `std::cbegin(s)` always works if you want the container itself to be immutable (which isn't an issue with `span` to begin with).

---

<sup>†</sup>Technically, implementation defined, not necessary `int const*`, but this is a useful fiction for explanatory purposes.

Comment: Oh right yeah that's confusing. Personally I'd probably prefer if `cbegin` etc. would return a const iterator, but I agree it would bring about some confusion.
So what would now be the best way to get a const iterator over the elements?

Comment: @SWdV You'd have to convert the `span<T>` itself to a `span<T const>` first.

Comment: What is "shallow const"?

Comment: So cbegin() on any span<> should return T const *. What's worng with that ?

Why does it HAVE to have shallow const ? What's wrong with the good old const propagation ?

Comment: @Toughy Because const propagation isn't really meaningful for `span` - you can just cheaply copy it to remove the `const`.